# React Native testing a race redux-saga effect not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

I am trying to test one of my saga functions, and in it, it has a `race`.
My code and my test race look almost identical, yet the race test seems to fail

```
  // in my saga
  yield race({
    delay: delay(waitLength),
    cancel: take(smartlook.actions.cancelDelay)
  });

  // part of the test
  .race({
    delay: delay(recordTimeLength),
    cancel: take(smartlookActions.cancelDelay)
  })
```

I have verified that `waitLength` and `recordTimeLength` are the same because they are both needed as part of a previous step in the test anyway which works. the `take` action are pointing to the exact same action, just named slightly differently in the import due to name conflicts.

when i run my test i get

```
SagaTestError:
race expectation unmet:

Expected
--------
{ delay:
   { _40: 0,
     _65: 0,
     _55: null,
     _72: null,
     '@@redux-saga/CANCEL_PROMISE': [Function] },
  cancel:
   { '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
     TAKE: { pattern: { [Function: actionCreator] toString: [Function] } } } }

Actual:
------
1. { delay:
   { _40: 1,
     _65: 0,
     _55: null,
     _72:
      { onFulfilled: { [Function: currCb] cancel: [Object] },
        onRejected: [Function],
        promise: { _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null } },
     '@@redux-saga/CANCEL_PROMISE': [Function] },
  cancel:
   { '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
     TAKE: { pattern: { [Function: actionCreator] toString: [Function] } } } }
```

I have no idea why the `delay` is different in the test compared to the real code, if anyone knows how this should work please let me know.

**Pasting more code for context below**

in saga:

```
export function* recordThenWait(waitLength) {
  const isRecording = yield select(smartlook.selectors.getSmartlookIsRecording);
  if (!isRecording) {
    yield put(smartlook.actions.resumeRecording());
  }
  yield race({
    delay: delay(waitLength),
    cancel: take(smartlook.actions.cancelDelay)
  });
  yield put(smartlook.actions.pauseRecording());
}
```

in test (tests more than just the function above):

```
  return expectSaga(Smartlook, {recordTimeLength, now})
    .withState(initialState)
    .dispatch(appStarted())
    .put(smartlookActions.recordAppStart())
    .fork(smartlook.recordThenWait, recordTimeLength)
    .put(smartlookActions.resumeRecording()) //works till here
    .race({
      delay: delay(recordTimeLength),
      cancel: take(smartlookActions.cancelDelay)
    })
    .put(smartlookActions.pauseRecording())
    .run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that `delay` itself is not an effect, and the race needs an effect to work properly, so I just changed the race to use a `call` on the delay instead in the actual and test

```
yield race({
  delay: call(delay, waitLength),
  cancel: take(smartlook.actions.cancelDelay)
});
```